# Can't get figures side by side no matter what?

Tags: floats

I've been trying to get these figures side by side, but they keep ending up as stacked. I've looked at a bunch of solutions, but none of them have helped me. Here's my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{actualcapacitor.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{likecapacitor.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Try `0.4\linewidth`.

Comment: You need to use `%` in the correct locations in order to make two `.5\linewidth`s fit within the line. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) `\hfill` is not necessary here.

Comment: Please do not ask a question both on the Reddit LaTeX group and also here.  I took the time to answer it there, not knowing that someone had already answered it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
test

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{myfoto}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{myfoto}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and may be you need

```
width=\linewidth
```

as i do here